# Basic Renovate Configuration for Angular Project

Tags: angular, renovate

I have a private angular project repo and new to it and installed renovate plugin on GitHub. It has created a basic config in `renovate.json` as below

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ]
}
```

Then did some reading and this was recommended for Angular project (could be wrong)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base",
    "github>angular/angular:renovate.json"
  ]
}
```

I have a few questions

1. Is this config correct or can you recommend something better?
2. Goal is to get notified for new `package.json` update and get a PR pulled for it so that I can build locally, test and merge manually
3. Any way to auto tag these PR with the default GitHub label of `dependencies`
4. Will it create a single PR for common package updates?
5. If I close a PR without merging if I feel I don't want to do it, how do I not make it recreate it?
6. Is there a way to not suggest major upgrades if build fails or should we still create PR and leave it failed?

New to this and basically looking for a recommended config for my project. Any other plugin or option to add, please let me know

This is what I have currently done

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base",
    "github>angular/angular:renovate.json"
  ],
  "labels": ["dependencies"],
  "pinDigests": false,
  "lockFileMaintenance": {"enabled": true}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that SO is meant for specific question rather than opinionated / looking for recommendations questions. I will however answer some of your questions.*

> 1. Is this config correct or can you recommend something better?

I don't think extending `github>angular/angular:renovate.json` brings anything. Not sure where you read that. The file doesn't even exist.

> 2. Goal is to get notified for new package.json update and get a PR pulled for it so that I can build locally, test and merge manually

Yup, that's out of the box Renovate behaviour.

> 3. Any way to auto tag these PR with the default GitHub label of dependencies

As you find out, `"labels": ["dependencies"]` does the job.

You can also use the [`label`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-default/#labelarg0) preset.

> 4. Will it create a single PR for common package updates?

It depends what you cann "common packages". For Angular for instance, it will create a single PR for all angular-xxx modules yes.

Depending on the manager, this can be done automatically if the manager has a notion of "group" like Maven for instance. For NPM I believe it's driven by the `@angular/` prefix and/or `groups` presets, like https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-group/#groupangularmonorepo.

> 5. If I close a PR without merging if I feel I don't want to do it, how do I not make it recreate it?

That's the default behaviour.

You can enable the [dependency dashboard](https://docs.renovatebot.com/key-concepts/dashboard/#how-to-enable-the-dashboard) to have an overview of closed PRs.

> 6. Is there a way to not suggest major upgrades if build fails or should we still create PR and leave it failed?

IMHO you should leave it fail, that's the purpose of Renovate: letting you know there's an update but your code doesn't work with it yet. You may close the PR or just keep it until you fix your code.

---

Overall, just start using it and over time if you have a specific need, dig into all the possible options to customize your experience.